# Using Parse and QuickBlox together

Tags: ios, networking, parse-platform, quickblox

Im very new to the backend. Im making a plan to build an iOS Social App that uses Parse for the backend. But since Parse hasn't supported real-time chat feature so I have an idea that uses the Quickblox chat API to build my real-time chat feature. Im not sure whether it is possible or not so I ask here.

Honestly I haven't try anything because I just make my plan. It must be clear before I start so I will build my app faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible.

QuickBlox user model has **external_user_id** field, you can connect Parse user and QB through this parameter. Or vise-a-versa.

Next, for example, you use Parse user. And you would like to start chat with other Parse user.
You should:

1. Get QuickBlox user by Parse user.
2. Login to QuickBlox chat
3. Send message.

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Integrate_QuickBlox_with_your_existing_User_Base

Also, QuickBlox has the same features wich has Parse. I recommend you to review your requirements and maybe you no need to use Parse because in any cases use 2 platforms it will be a bit complicated to support.

Comment: Thank you. It is very easy to understand.

Comment: I will think about your advice that using 1 platfrom :D.